# Retrieving eloquent models with constraints on both the parent and child/associated model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, data-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve all Eloquent Models that match a particular field in the Parent Model ('Event') and the child model ('Dates').

I've hit an issue whereby Laravel is stating that my field ('date') doesn't exist in the child class, but I can't understand why. Can someone please point me in the right direction and explain where I've gone wrong?

Essentially, what I'm trying to achieve is the retrieval of all Events with the approved tag being true AND where the event date is of a particular day, in this case the 10th.

I've done some searching around and looked at some of the examples in the Laravel documentation. I've set up the ('Event') model to have a one to many relationship with the ('dates') model. I can see that I can chain queries together, but things get a little confusing when dealing with more than one model at a time (in the same query)

This is my attempt at retrieving the data.

```
public function calender()
    {
        $events = Event::where('approved', true)->with('EventDates')->whereDay('date', '10')->get();
        return view('events.calender');
    }
```

This is a snippet from my ('Event') Model. I've only included the most relevant information here as there are many attributes .

```
class Event extends Model
{
    //

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function dates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventDate');
    }
}
```

This is a snippet from my ('EventDate') model migration file showing that 'date' is indeed a field of the ('EventDate') model. Once again, I've just included the most relevant function here.

```
class CreateEventDatesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('event_dates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->date('date')->nullable();
            $table->time('startTime')->nullable();
            $table->time('endTime')->nullable();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('event_id');
            $table->index('event_id');
        });
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve a list of the matching Events that have the approved attribute set to true, and the Event Dates on a particular day (xxxx-xx-10)

Right now, I'm getting the error that the date column can't be found:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `events` where day(`date`) = 10 and `approved` = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```php
    $events = Event::where('approved', true)
        ->with(['dates' => function ($query) {
            return $query->whereDay('date', '10');
        }])
        ->get();
```

Note: I assume your relation between an Event and it's EventDate is called `dates`

In this way you are applying filtering by day on the related data (`EventDate`) and not on the `Event` model.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! This produces the result set I was looking for in the beginning!

Comment: If that resolves your issue, please mark the answer as accepted to flag the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you should mention the table name for the date column.

```
->whereDay('event_dates.date', '10')
```

Comment: The issue is still there unfortunately. I get the same kind of error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'event_dates.date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `events` where `approved` = 1 and day(`event_dates`.`date`) = 10)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way around using the eloquent commands by using the DB Query builder instead and it now works (taking into account Shankar's point above)

I altered the code to this (It's a little more specific than what I wrote before, but it should be able to guide others to solving their issue):

````
for($day = 5; $day <12; $day++)
        {
            $events = DB::table('events')
                ->join('event_dates', 'events.id', '=', 'event_dates.event_id')
                ->select('events.*', 'event_dates.startTime as startTime', 'event_dates.endTime AS endTime')->where('events.approved', '=', true)->whereDay('event_dates.date', '=', $day)
                ->orderBy('event_dates.startTime', 'asc')->get();

            array_push($events_list, $events);
        }
    ```
I can't understand why the Eloquent queries couldn't find the table, but this seems to work, so for those stuck, this may be less "eloquent" but at least it works ;-;
````